# C fscanf reading in the correct format

Tags: c, file, format, scanf

I'm totally stuck with fscanf formatizer in `C`

```
Alice:(44;69) Bob:(74;68) John:(57;98)
```

This is what I need to read from file. `Name:(score1, score2)`. But I failed to construct the correct formatizer for it:

```
while(fscanf(f, "%[a-zA-Z]%[;(]%d %d", &buff, &garbage, &s1, &s2)!= EOF){
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you check e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you can see that you can add an asterisk to a format code to suppress assignment, so no need to pass "garbage" variables.

Secondly for your problem, the numbers are split with semicolon, but you have a space in the format which corresponds to whitespace.

In fact, due to the pattern-matching functionality built-in into `scanf` you should be able to simplify the format specification to e.g.

```
fscanf(f, " %[^:]:(%d;%d)", buff, &s1, &s2)
```

The `"%[^:]"` format reads everything as a string until it sees a colon. The rest of the format then matches the colon, the left parenthesis, a decimal number, a semicolon, another decimal number and a right parenthesis. I also added a leading space in the format, to skip leading whitespace if there is any.